# Symfony 4: remove collection from entity

Tags: symfony, collections, entity, relation

I have a product entity and product image entity. I want to use soft delete on product entity only and make a delete on product image entity.
The soft delete works fine. When I delete the product, the deleted_at column is set to current time.
So I would like to delete product image when the deleted_at column is updated.
I was wondering if I can do it directly in entity class? and how?

Product entity where I try to make the collection delation in setDeletedAt function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProductImage", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $productImages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted_at;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productImages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setDeletedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $deleted_at): self
    {
        // Here I try to remove images when deleted_at column is updated
        $productImage = $this->getProductImages();
        $this->removeProductImage($productImage);

        $this->deleted_at = $deleted_at;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProductImage[]
     */
    public function getProductImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productImages;
    }

    public function addProductImage(ProductImage $productImage): self
    {
        if (!$this->productImages->contains($productImage)) {
            $this->productImages[] = $productImage;
            $productImage->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProductImage(ProductImage $productImage): self
    {
        if ($this->productImages->contains($productImage)) {
            $this->productImages->removeElement($productImage);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($productImage->getProduct() === $this) {
                $productImage->setProduct(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

But when I make the soft delete, setDeletedAt() is called and the following error is returned:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Product::removeProductImage() must be an instance of App\Entity\ProductImage, instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection given, called in ...
```

Thanks for your help!

---- **UPDATE** ----

Solution provided by John works fine:

```
foreach ($this->getProductImages() as $pi) {
    $this->removeProductImage($pi);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty self-explaining error:

at this point:

```
    $productImage = $this->getProductImages();
    $this->removeProductImage($productImage);
```

you are passing a collection instead a single ProductImage object.

to delete them all, just do:

```
foreach ($this->getProductImages() as $pi) {
    $this->removeProductImage($pi);
}
```